# Upload image to server with ionic/angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want upload image to server with ionic. 
I use this factory:

```js
(function () {
    function ius($q, $ionicLoading, $cordovaFile ) {  
        var service = {};
        service.uploadImage = uploadImage;
        return service;
        function uploadImage(imageURI) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var fileSize;
            var percentage;
            // Find out how big the original file is
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                    fileSize = fileObj.size;
                    // Display a loading indicator reporting the start of the upload
                    $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Uploading Picture : ' + 0 + '%' });
                    // Trigger the upload
                    uploadFile();
                });
            });
            function uploadFile() {
                // Add the Cloudinary "upload preset" name to the headers
                var uploadOptions = {
                    params: { 'upload_preset': CLOUDINARY_CONFIGS.UPLOAD_PRESET }  //CLOUDINARY_CONFIGS.UPLOAD_PRESET
                };
                $cordovaFile
                  // Your Cloudinary URL will go here
                  .uploadFile(CLOUDINARY_CONFIGS.API_URL, imageURI, uploadOptions)  //

                  .then(function (result) {
                      // Let the user know the upload is completed
                      $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Upload Completed', duration: 1000 });
                      // Result has a "response" property that is escaped
                      // FYI: The result will also have URLs for any new images generated with 
                      // eager transformations
                      var response = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(result.response));
                      deferred.resolve(response);
                  }, function (err) {
                      // Uh oh!
                      $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Upload Failed', duration: 3000 });
                      deferred.reject(err);
                  }, function (progress) {
                      // The upload plugin gives you information about how much data has been transferred 
                      // on some interval.  Use this with the original file size to show a progress indicator.
                      percentage = Math.floor(progress.loaded / fileSize * 100);
                      $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Uploading Picture : ' + percentage + '%' });
                  });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
    angular.module('App').factory('ImageUploadService', ius);
})();
```

And i call this function :

```
'Use Strict';
angular.module('App').controller('editeventController', function ($scope,ImageUploadService) {


    $scope.upload = function () {

        ImageUploadService.uploadImage("img/test.jpg").then(  
        function (result) {

            var url = result.secure_url || '';
            var urlSmall;

            if (result && result.eager[0]) urlSmall = result.eager[0].secure_url || '';

            // Do something with the results here.

            $cordovaCamera.cleanup();

        },
        function (err) {

            // Do something with the error here
            $cordovaCamera.cleanup();

        });

    }
```

But, when I try to upload, I have this error:

> TypeError: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function
>       at Object.uploadImage (http://localhost:8100/js/services/utils.js:177:20)
>       at Scope.$scope.upload (http://localhost:8100/views/editevent/editevent.js:199:28)
>       at fn (eval at  (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26457:15),
>   :4:209)
>       at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62386:9
>       at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28)
>       at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29257:23)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62385:13)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16583:21)
>       at triggerMouseEvent (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2948:7)
>       at tapClick (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2937:3)

[edit]

I use requestFileSystem instead of resolveLocalFileSystemURL

```
  window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

            window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);

            function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
                var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
                console.log(directoryEntry);
                directoryEntry.getFile(imageURI, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

                    console.log(fileEntry);
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                      //  writer.write("This is the text inside readme file");

                        var pathOfFile = fileEntry.fullPath;
                        console.log(pathOfFile);
                        fileSize = fileEntry.size;
                        // Display a loading indicator reporting the start of the upload
                        $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Uploading Picture : ' + 0 + '%' });
                        uploadFile();

                    }, function (error) {
                        alert("Error occurred while writing to file. Error is: " + error.message);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                    alert("Error occurred while getting a pointer to file. Error is: " + error.message);
                });
            }

            function onError(evt) {
                alert("Error occurred during request to file system pointer. Error is: " + evt.message);
            }
```

Now I have this error:

> The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed
>   its storage quota.

Comment: use requestFileSystem instead of  resolveLocalFileSystemURL.And see if the upload is happening

Comment: I have the error: "ReferenceError: requestFileSystem is not defined" . I'm not sure to install the cordova plugin file correctly. How I verify it?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake. Now I have this error: "The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota."
I edited my post

Comment: ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.file   add this plugin and try once more with your old code

Comment: I have the same error: "TypeError: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function " 
And when I add this plugin I have this message:
"Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Notice: org.apache.cordova.file has been automatically converted to cordova-plug
in-file to be fetched from npm. This is due to our old plugins registry shutting
 down.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via npm
Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Saving plugin to package.json file"